# Programmatically "tap" the Microphone key on the iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

When the app segues to `ChatViewController`, I want to programmatically make the keyboard appear and press the microphone/dictation button, so it's basically like segueing to a Siri-like feature. See code below.

```
@IBAction func micPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    /* Somehow simulate tapping the microphone key */
}
```

Is there a way to do this?